# Question regarding syntax of $\bigcap$ definition

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know what this definition is supposed to do. However just looking at the syntax, i cannot explain it to myself.

$$
\bigcap M := \{x \mid \forall y \in M : x \in y\}
$$

Could somebody please explain me how to read this definition (not what it does, but rather how to read it close to the definition's syntax so that it is easier to understand)?

Comment: The intersection of a family of sets is a set which contains exactly those elements who are contained (*as elements*) in each of the sets in the family.  Compare to something like $A\cap B\cap C=\{x~:~x\in A\wedge x\in B\wedge x\in C\}$.  Here, we are just referring to a family of sets and applying the intersection operation to the entire family $\bigcap \{A,B,C\} = A\cap B\cap C$ and having generalized this so as to not require writing out every member of the family

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{array}{cccccc}
\bigcap M
 & := 
 & \{
 & x 
 & \mid
 & \forall
 &  y  \in M : 
 &  x \in y
 & \}  \\
\text{This “$\bigcap M$” thing}
 & \text{means}
 & \text{the set of}
 & \text{all $x$} 
 & \text{such that}
 & \text{for every}
 & \text{ set $y$ in $M$,}
 & \text{$x$ is in set $y$}
 & \text{.}
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to see it this way: Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. Let $M=\{A,B\}.$ Define $$\bigcap M = \bigcap_{y\in M} y.$$

Then $\bigcap M = A \cap B,$ and if you expand the definition above you can see that it fits the one you provided.